# Javascript get mp3 file duration from Google Drive

Tags: javascript, duration, queryselector

I've taken a code from a Youtube video that implements a music player for your website. It is a simple one and I'm not really good with JS so I just used it. However, the original code uses mp3 files from local storage, but I need them to be sourced from Google Drive. So I changed the code to what I need and the player works. However, the music queue does not.

The console gives this error;

script.js:191 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '#[https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1xx-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1xx-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%27) is not a valid selector.
at file:///D:/My%20Files/My%20Portfolio/js/script.js:191:34

Note: I've hidden the id of the file for privacy :pp

What the code does is; it inserts an array of song details into an ul tag in the HTML.

```
const ulTag = wrapper.querySelector("ul");

for (let i = 0; i < allMusic.length; i++) {
  
  console.log("traversing array of music at index: " + i);
  let liTag = `<li li-index="${i + 1}">
                <div class="row">
                  <span>${allMusic[i].name}</span>
                  <p>${allMusic[i].artist}</p>
                </div>
                <span id="${allMusic[i].src}" class="audio-duration">3:40</span>
                <audio class="${allMusic[i].src}" src="${allMusic[i].src}"></audio>
              </li>`;
  ulTag.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", liTag); //inserting the li inside ul tag

  let liAudioDuartionTag = ulTag.querySelector(`#${allMusic[i].src}`); //ERROR IS HERE!
  let liAudioTag = ulTag.querySelector(`.${allMusic[i].src}`);
  liAudioTag.addEventListener("loadeddata", ()=>{
    let duration = liAudioTag.duration;
    let totalMin = Math.floor(duration / 60);
    let totalSec = Math.floor(duration % 60);
    if(totalSec < 10){ //if sec is less than 10 then add 0 before it
      totalSec = `0${totalSec}`;
    };
    liAudioDuartionTag.innerText = `${totalMin}:${totalSec}`; //passing total duation of song
    liAudioDuartionTag.setAttribute("t-duration", `${totalMin}:${totalSec}`); //adding t-duration attribute with total duration value
  });
}
```

How the music details are stored in the array is;

```
let allMusic = [
    {
        name: "John Doe - Rock n Roll",
        artist: "Tesla",
        img: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxxxxxxxxx/hqdefault.jpg",
        src: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1xx-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
];
```

I do not know queryselectors very well, and I read pages of documentation but I couldn't find any solutions. Maybe Javascript somehow gets messed up with links in the selector but I couldn't get around it as well.

Any ideas are welcome and thanks in advance...

Comment: change `#` to `.` so it reads:
ulTag.querySelector(`.${allMusic[i].src}`);

Comment: Just tried and same error....

Comment: Maybe an extra info would help. This same code works for local storage without any links but only for a name such as "music-1", "music-2" etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the problem is now solved. The code was trying to find an element on the HTML code, now I understand query selectors, and it was creating the ul list item with an id of the google drive link, and then for some reason (probably escaping), the id could not be selected.

I added an extra attribute in the music list array and I inserted the list elements with those id's, which could now be selected with the query selector and now it's working.